# Node on Snappy Ubuntu

Tags: nodejs, ubuntu-core

Does Snappy Ubuntu support Node.js?

I need to run a node server on Ubuntu core. If yes, is there any way to do it.

Comment: Look into installing docker onto snappy, and use that to install nodejs. Note that you will need to look for arm / rasperry version of node if you plan to use that. most docker apps are for regular x86 CPUs, and arm isn't that well supported on docker yet

Answer (score 1):

This is possible through snapcraft. Have a look at https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/snapcraft-advanced-features/ (and search for nodejs in the page). This should give you the first good hints for your next steps!