# Is it possible to install Node.js and NPM on Ubuntu Core?

Tags: ubuntu-core, nodejs, npm

I would like to know if Node.js is available in Ubuntu Core and if yes, how I can install it.

I see this issue [Node on Snappy Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/740726/node-on-snappy-ubuntu), but it says nothing.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

I used the info here: [Install applications in Ubuntu core](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902905/install-applications-in-ubuntu-core)

> sudo snap install classic --devmode --edge

then

> sudo classic

To enable aptitude, then your normal:

> sudo apt-get install nodejs nodejs-legacy npm
>
> sudo npm i -g npm

To get NPM to version: 3.5.2 and Node to: 4.2.6

Then NPM can't be updated further this way, as it complains about the version of Node that breaks NPM. Normally to update NPM I'd use 'n':

> sudo npm i -g n
>
> sudo n stable

But as NPM doesn't work with this version of Node that's not happening.

I found this [How can I update my nodeJS to the latest version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version) and used:

> sudo apt-get install curl
>
> curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
>
> sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

Now Node version is: 8.9.4, and NPM can once again be updated as usual; and you can also use NPM to install 'n' and update Node however you want if you need a specific version.

Then you can install git to clone your app or do whatever.

You've probably already solved your problem, but offering a possible solution in case anyone else is after one.

Answer (score 1):

If you need Nodejs for your application, convert your application to snap (with snapcraft) and install it `snap install <your application>` . Nodejs is then packaged in the snap and you do not need to extra install it. Otherwise may be Ubuntu Server is better suited for you.